# Tool for modelling uniform groundwater flow from points and isopotential lines (elevation contours) - QGIS

Tags: qgis, flow, flow-direction

I am going to investigate where a specific particle in a groundwater system will be found in 10 years.

I have the following data:

- A vector point layer with x and y coordinates of points I want to investigate.
- Contour lines showing the isopotential lines of the groundwater table. Just like elevation contour lines

I want to create a new layer showing the location of the points in 10 years based on the elevation data of the groundwater table. I am assuming a uniform flow meaning that the slope of the groundwater table is the only factor controlling the speed of the water molecule.

Any suggestions for an appropriate tool in QGIS to show this?